# Should random variable be a one-to-one function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let us consider a simple example. The toss of a dice with 6 numbers. The sample space, that is the set of all possible outcomes (elementary events) is $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

A random variable is a mapping from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$ (consider $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity). That is:
$$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$

Probability $P$ is defined over events $F$, that is the set of all possible subsets of $\Omega$. For example, $\{1, 3, 5\}$ is an event.

**The problem**

What I can't understand is the following:
Let us say that our random variable is defined in the following way:
$$ X(\omega) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad \text{if $\omega < 4$} \\
1, \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
When I ask what is the probability $P(X=0)$, essentially I am asking what is the probability of the event $\{1, 2, 3\}$. Similarly, when I ask what is the probability $P(X=1)$, essentially I am asking what is the probability of the event $\{4, 5, 6\}$.

By using a random variable that isn't one-to-one I can't describe the probability of an outcome/elementary event. Is this problematic? Should the random variable be a one-to-one function?

Comment: Every constant function is a random variable, regardless of the structure of the probability space.

Comment: But you can already describe the probability of a single outcome $\omega$. It's $P(\omega)$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, but I can't describe it using a random variable.

Comment: On $(\Omega,{\cal A},\mathbb P)$ you can have as many random variables as you want. Most of them are far from being one-to-one.

Comment: Why do think it's important that every random variable on a probability space needs to separate points like that?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Because otherwise we can't talk about the probability of a single outcome $\omega$.

Comment: @user599310: For every outcome $\omega$ there exists a random variable $X$ which takes the value $1$ at $\omega$ and $0$ elsewhere. The expected value of this variable $X$ is $P(\omega)$.  What do you really mean by “we can't talk about the probability of a single outcome $\omega$”?

Comment: Should the sum of random variables be a random variable? The product? If so, you need to admit random variables which are not one-to-one functions

Comment: @MatthewLeingang From the example I gave, how can you calculate $P(\omega=2)$? (Note the definition I gave for $X(\omega)$).

Comment: As you wrote, the probability $P$ is defined over events, and every subset of $\Omega$ is an event. So $P(\{2\})$ is known before the variable $X$ is even defined. We cannot isolate $\{2\}$ using values of $X$, but we don't need to.